# Selecting option under dropdown using angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I have written following code in .js file

```
var appMod = angular.module('appMod',[]);

appMod.controller('domainCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.admins = [{"type":["Kerberos","Department","Office"],"office":["NA","Bangalore","NY","NJ"]}];
});
```

Now i want to select an option from a drop down of type and office.
I have written following code in .html

```
<label for="typeOfAccess" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Type of Access :</label>
<div class="col-sm-1">
<select name="typeOfAccess" data-ng-model="newDomain.typeOfAccess">
<option data-ng-repeat="typeOfAccess in admin.type" value="typeOfAccess">{{typeOfAccess}}</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Please suggest what to do.

Comment: Why doesn't this work?  Can you provide a plunker demonstrating the problem?  How does 'office' relate to the code you have shared?

Answer (score 0):

That is not how you defined options for a select in angularjs.

Please check documentation [angularjs docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select)

This is how it should look like:

```
<label for="typeOfAccess" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Type of Access :</label>
<div class="col-sm-1">
<select name="typeOfAccess" 
        data-ng-model="newDomain.typeOfAccess" 
        data-ng-options="typeOfAccess for typeOfAccess in admin.type">
</select>
</div>
```

Let me know if it works after making those changes.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **ng-value** to save selected option .
I had same problem here once: [Display details of selected options in Angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23307412/display-details-of-selected-options-in-angularjs)

```
$scope.selection = {
    typeOfAccess: null
};

    <label for="typeOfAccess" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Type of Access :</label>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <select name="typeOfAccess" data-ng-model="newDomain.typeOfAccess">
         <div data-ng-repeat="typeOfAccess in admin.type">
          <label><option value="typeOfAccess" ng-value="typeOfAccess" ng-model="selection.typeOfAccess"> </label> </option>
         </div>
        </select>
     </div>

Selected campaign: {{ selection.typeOfAccess }}
```